# Is it necessary to stop animation in Activity's onStop()?

Tags: android, android-animation, activity-lifecycle

Just curious about this question. Is it necessary to stop animation in `onStop()` of activity?

Comment: If you do its better if dont `Android will take care of it`.

Comment: @jackjay I am doing animation like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481035/android-first-time-animation-is-not-smooth please see my question.

Comment: @jackjay if android will take care of it, why it's better to stop the animation manually?

Comment: So what you want, do i answer that question??

Comment: @jackjay if possible please answer that question as well I have spent more time on that issue "Why first time animation is not smooth?".

Comment: I think it depends on your case.Ex: if your animation is infinite animation, you can stop it when onPause (or `onStop` because user no longer can see it), then resume it when `onResume`. In case your animation is a short time (or not repeat), you can add a `listener` by calling `setAnimationListener` and stop it whenever the animation is stop.

Answer (score 2):

In `onStop()`, the app should release almost all resources that aren't needed while the user is not using it.

`AnimationDrawable` loads all of the frames into memory at once for good performance.Sometimes if VM can not provide such memory, it will result in `OutOfMemoryError`. So, it's best practice to release all resources in `onStop()`.

[According to Android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), one should use the `onPause()` to pause operations like animations:

> Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity.
>   This is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data,
>   stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, etc.